# Set value in Backbone.Form after fetch from the server

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hi I am newbie in Backbone and JS.

I need to fetch data from the server and put this value as the default to `planProviderMode` choice radio button. So i fetch the data in `defaultMode` variable. But the call is a asynchronous and I receive a value after the `planProviderMode: defaultMode.value` code has been executed.

```
var PlanProviderMode = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: '/rest/enrollment/step/plan-provider-mode'
});
var defaultMode = new PlanProviderMode;

defaultMode.fetch({
success: function() {
  // recieve correct data
}
});

var formItems = new Backbone.Form({
template: tpl,
className: 'wizard-content',
schema: {
  planProviderMode: {
    template: formTpl,
    type: 'Radio',
    options: [
      {
        label: 'By Plan',
        val: 'BY_PLAN',
        custom: {
          img: '../resources/img/by-plan.jpg'
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'By Provider',
        val: 'BY_PROVIDER',
        custom: {
          img: '../resources/img/by-provider.jpg'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
//here i put the default value
data: {
  planProviderMode: defaultMode.value
}
});
```

How could I set the fetched value to the form.

Please let me know if the question is not described well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write such code in `success callback` function which is executed only after the fetch request is completed succesfully.

```
var PlanProviderMode = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: '/rest/enrollment/step/plan-provider-mode'
});
var defaultMode = new PlanProviderMode;

defaultMode.fetch({
success: function() {
  // recieve correct data
//here you put the default value
data: {
  planProviderMode: defaultMode.value
}
}
});

var formItems = new Backbone.Form({
template: tpl,
className: 'wizard-content',
schema: {
  planProviderMode: {
    template: formTpl,
    type: 'Radio',
    options: [
      {
        label: 'By Plan',
        val: 'BY_PLAN',
        custom: {
          img: '../resources/img/by-plan.jpg'
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'By Provider',
        val: 'BY_PROVIDER',
        custom: {
          img: '../resources/img/by-provider.jpg'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks

'formItems.setValue({ planProviderMode: defaultMode.get('value') });'

 this code works

Answer (score 0):

Backnone has a function called "parse" that helps you in this cases.

This function will always be called from backbone before the data from server populate the model.

Take a read in parse method.

There's a answer here.
[how to override Backbone's parse function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037984/how-to-override-backbones-parse-function)

Hope it helps